# How to extract meaningful extraction when given a query for a structured dataframe using Python/NLU?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition, watson-nlu

I am finding this task very challenging and unable to find an approach.

**Given**:Structred Dataframe of FinanacialReport
[Finanacial Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cFJy.png)

I want to identify the intents given a text query.
To be more precise: If I'm given a text query "**What is Fiscal 2013 of Latin America?**"

**Output**:388.00

The challenge I'm facing is it can be done for unstructured text/paragraphs suing NER?
But how to proceed when given a dataframe like this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it as follows (using Rasa):

1) Provide NLU training data where you tag your required entities. E.g. an entity `location`  and a entity `metric`. This probably best done with the `crf` [component](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#crfentityextractor). Maybe it's worth combining it with [lookup tables](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/training-data-format/).

2) Run a custom action `action_query_financial_data` when the intent for the text query is classified

3) In the custom action, use the extracted entities to query the dataframe.